# Saving colored output regardless of the source

Tags: shell, pipe, colors, tty, pty

How can I save colored output to a file regardless of the source when the sources turn coloring off if they detect their stdout isn't a terminal?

Comment: Coloring is usually done by the programs displaying the output. If you want to save some text with colored formatting, use openoffice or similar text processing tools.

Comment: I'm not trying to write a document here.

Comment: What are you trying then?

Comment: Solve the problem of saving output colored with ANSI control characters in a way that doesn't rely on app-specific switches such as "--color-always" given to the output-producing app.

Comment: Have you tried using `script`?

Comment: @Celada I'm not familiar with `script`, but I've already solved the problem. If `script` solves it too, feel free to show how, and I'll upvote it or accept it.

Answer (score 2):

The following script I managed to put together seems to do it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

require 'pty'
PTY.spawn(*ARGV) do |r,w,pid|
  begin
    while $_ = r.gets
      STDOUT.print $_
    end
  rescue Errno::EIO
  end
end
```

It runs its CLI arguments in a pseudoterminal and forwards the output to STDOUT.

Usage example:

```
./script.rb ls --color=auto >| file #file will have them ANSI color code sequences in it because ls did run in a terminal.
```